# Cron Job that access django Models

Tags: django, django-models

**What i have done?**

I have written a small application in django with few models with sqlite3 as backend. Now i want to write a python code that clears the database elements based on certain condition.

**Question:**

How can i achieve the above requirement?

Comment: What are the conditions? What have you tried? What approaches are you considering? What are the problems with those approaches?

Comment: I have a table of 10,000 records with 'date' as one of its column. i would like screen the table periodically and remove old records. I wanted to do it through cron job with python script, where i needed to access my database through django

Comment: Then I think what Ludwik suggested is a good approach. You can have your cron job call the management command regularly. Another approach is to run a task queue like Celery

Comment: Thanks timmy ;). I like your timely response. Sure will check with that.

Answer (score 5):

I think the cleanest way to do this is to [write your own django-admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

You can then run the command using manage.py:

```
python manage.py your_command
```

Having a command that can be run in shell, you can easily put in into your crontab. Optionally django-admin commands can receive command line arguments, if needed.